# Swift Search Objects

Tags: arrays, object, swiftui, uisearchbar, swiftui-list

I want to create a search function so that a user is able to search through a list in my app.
[image: Screenshot of the SearchBar]

I initialize this list of racetracks like this:

```
 var tracks: [Track] = tracksData
```

and implement the search like this:

```
NavigationSearch(text: $searchText, searchResultsContent: {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Search Results for \(searchText)")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding([.top, .bottom])

                    Divider()
                    
                    ForEach(Track.filter { self.searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.contains(self.searchText) }, id: \.self) { fruit in
                        Text(fruit)
                        Divider()
                    }

                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()
            })
```

this is from Mark van Wijnen's [medium article](https://medium.com/@crystalminds/integrate-uisearchcontroller-in-ios-apps-using-swiftui-f3d31d04a93)

But I always receive the errors shown below:
[image: Screenshot of the code snippet]
[image: Screenshot of the build error]

I know the error is caused by the datatype I am using for my tracks objects, because
*Mark van Wijnen* used a simple String Array, but I am unable to fix this search function so that it is able to search my Array of Objects. I hope someone is kind enough to help me with this.
Thanks in advance

Link to a package with sample data:
https://workupload.com/file/cbky5ucgM26

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks, I added a link to package with sample files.

Comment: Your code examples should be
…Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem
…Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself
…Reproducible – Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem. You likely won't find anybody here that will download a zip file. We should be able copy and paste the code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close! Breaking the code apart would have given better errors and you would have found it. ForEach requires the item to be hashable if self is used as the id. Using Track's id property in self probably cleared the bug. However, it took a little work to get there, so here is the refactored code.

Break out search filter into TrackModel so multiple field can be searched:

```
func search(_ query: String) -> Bool {
    let searchable = [title, headline, description] + details

    return searchable.filter({ $0.contains(query) }).count > 0
}
```

Next, add a calculated property in TrackView3 to encapsulate the list:

```
var filtered : [Track] {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        return tracks
    } else {
        return tracks.filter({ $0.search(searchText) })
    }
}
```

Now the ForEach doesn't have all that search stuff and its tidy form:

```
ForEach(filtered, id: \.id) { track in
 TrackDetailView(tracks: track)
 Divider()
```

}

Paul Hudson recently made a video with tips for better Swift Views. He covers encapsulating code in calculated properties. It makes for cleaner code and spares the coder from bugs in the declarative-tree (errors are not always helpful). [5 Steps to Better SwiftUI Views](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/226/5-steps-to-better-swiftui-views)

Comment: Thanks, this works great and the article is also very helpful. After implementing your changes the search works perfectly. My only issue is now that the Navigation Links on the search results are greyed out and not working. I embedded the TrackDetailView in a NavigationLink, as seen in the code below.`NavigationLink(destination: TrackDetailView(tracks: track)) {
                            TrackRowView(track: track)
                            }`

Comment: Will you kindly please mark as answered and start a new question with the new issue?

Comment: Thanks for you help, I opened a new thread for the NavigationLink issue :)